# Adding events to SVG text element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom-events

I have an svg element. I have added a `mousemove event` handler to it and it works fine.

Now I add text element on it and have `added mouseover event` handler on this too, but the event dosen't fire. Other elements like `path and line` are firing the events but not the `text` element.

Belowis my code for creating text element and binding the event handler to it.

```
function createXTickLabel(cx, cy, lbl, color) {
    var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var tlbl = document.createElementNS(svgns, "text");
    tlbl.setAttribute("fill", color);
    tlbl.setAttribute("x", cx);
    tlbl.setAttribute("y", cy);
    tlbl.textContent = lbl;
    tlbl.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "tklbl");
    tlbl.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseover", overTickLabel);
    return tlbl;
}

function overTickLabel(evt){
    // this function is not executed on mouseover
    $("#preview_grid").trigger("mouseover");
    console.log(evt);
}
```

Comment: `overTickLabel` is a function, not a string. This should work: `tlbl.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseover", "overTickLabel()");`

Comment: Oh,I missed to realize the type of the arguments the `setAttributeNS` method accepts. Thanks a lot.